# the default value is not going away when I select some other value in dropdown box

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-select

I have dropdown box with default value as the first value. But when I am selcting any other value in dropdown list the value in the dropdown box is remaining to default value.

```
<select ng-init="searchParams.countPerPage = perPageValues[0].val" ng-model="searchParams.countPerPage" ng-options="item.val as item.val for item in perPageValues | orderBy :'sequence'"  ng-change="track('perPageChange')" data-id="select-per-page"> </select>
```

This code produces:

```
<select ng-init="searchParams.countPerPage = perPageValues[0].val" ng-model="searchParams.countPerPage" ng-options="item.val as item.val for item in perPageValues | orderBy :'sequence'" ng-change="track('perPageChange')" data-id="select-per-page" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
<option value="0" selected="selected">25</option>
<option value="1">50</option>
<option value="2">100</option>
</select>
```

Comment: suggest you create a demo that replicates problem

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
item as item.val for item in...
```

You would then assign the entire object to ng-model and use the val property where that property's value is needed.

Without a working example to look at or edit that's just my gut reaction as to what is causing the problem.